# When the method valueOf may be absent?

Tags: javascript, object, tostring, value-of

I have this code. And I don't understand how it works.

```js
let obj = {
    valueOf: function () {
        return {};
    },
    toString: function () {
        return 222;
    }
};

console.log(Number(obj)); //222
```

According to this [source](https://javascript.info/object-toprimitive#summary), the conversion algorithm is:

> 1. Call `obj[Symbol.toPrimitive](hint)` if the method exists,
> 2. Otherwise if hint is "string" try `obj.toString()` and `obj.valueOf()`, whatever exists.
> 3. Otherwise if hint is "number" or "default" try `obj.valueOf()` and `obj.toString()`, whatever exists.

**Hint is number here. Then why is `obj.toString()` called? Is there no `obj.valueOf()`? Why? What kind of objects have this method? I can't find any useful information about this.**

And here's another example:

```js
var room = {
  number: 777,

  valueOf: function() { return this.number; },
  toString: function() { return 255; }
};

console.log( +room );  // 777
```

**Why is `obj.valueOf()` called in this case? Why does this method exist here, and doesn't in the first example? How does it work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the article you quoted:

> #### [Return types](https://javascript.info/object-toprimitive#return-types)
>
> …
> The only mandatory thing: these methods must return a primitive, not
> an object.
>
> > <sub>Historical notes</sub>
> > For historical reasons, if `toString` or `valueOf` returns an object,
> > there’s no error, but such value is ignored (like if the method didn’t
> > exist).

In your first snippet, *both* methods exists and are *tried*: first `obj.valueOf()`, but since it returns an empty object not a primitive value, `obj.toString()` is also called.

In your second snippet, `obj.valueOf()` already return the number `777`, which becomes the result.

Comment: *"`obj.valueOf()`, whatever exists"*, *"`obj.toString()`, whatever exists"*... Actually, in what kind of situations these methods can't exist? Just out of curiosity

Comment: @Ivan `Object.create(null)`, `{valueOf: null, toString: undefined}`

Comment: I got it. I just need to nullify these methods. But I still have one more question. When does `obj[Symbol.toPrimitive]` exist? I see that there's mostly no `obj[Symbol.toPrimitive]` in simple objects. So, in what cases this method can be?

Comment: @Ivan `Date` and `Symbol` instances have that method, also you can define it on your own objects and custom classes.